# Why doesn't cv2.transpose() write to destination?

Tags: python, numpy, opencv, image-processing, data-science

I am trying to transpose an image using opencv,python but when ı set the destination for it, it doesnt write to it so when ı look at output image ı only see a black screen. Why does that happen?

Here's my code;

```
import cv2
import numpy as np

a=np.zeros(image.shape).astype(image.dtype)
cv2.transpose(image,a)
cv2.imwrite("a.png",a)
cv2.imshow("hh",a)


cv2.waitKey(0)
cv2.destroyAllWindows()
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

documentation https://docs.opencv.org/master/d2/de8/group__core__array.html#ga46630ed6c0ea6254a35f447289bd7404

OpenCV is sensitive to matrices it can't completely modify (resize). it can do that for cv::Mat. it can't for numpy arrays.

simply use `a = cv2.transpose(image)`

Comment: thank you, sorry saw that late due to some occupation of mine :)